# No puedo abrir ficheros para escritura en partición NTFS

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ntfs

Desde que he instalado Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, no se porque, que ya no puedo abrir ficheros que están en una partición NTFS (antes, con la 18.04 no tenía problemas).

Sólo me permite abrir los ficheros en modo "Sólo lectura".

Tampoco puedo crear enlaces simbólicos de los ficheros que tengo en las particiones NTFS.

El caso es que creo que tengo bien montadas las particiones NTFS con el programa Discos.

¿Qué puede estar fallando?
¿Qué puedo probar?

Nota: estoy con el usuario que se crea por defecto al instalar el sistema, que entiendo, tiene los máximos permisos (SuperUsuario).

Comment: Voto por cerrar esta pregunta porque no trata sobre programación, tal como se establece en el [help/on-topic]. Esta pregunta podría pertenecer al sitio [SuperUser](https://superuser.com).

Comment: Gracias Mauricio. Tienes razón, disculpa (no sabia que eran sólo para preguntas sobre progracion). ¿Sabes de algún foro de Sistemas y Middleware (Tomcat) en Español?